# Unrecognized windows socket 10106 and nslooksup or DNS issue

Tags: java, windows, sockets

Im not really sure if this is the correct forum to post in, since Im sure this is not a Java issue. However, any help would be very much appreciated. I have been getting a very strange issue today. When I do a maven build, I get an
    Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
All dependency resolutions fail, but project still builds fine from local repo. However, when I run integration tests that require connection to other components I again get the
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
exception. Unit tests that do not require connection work fine.

I tried writing a simple test program, that has a socket connect to a server socket, but as soon as the server socket is instantiated I get the same exception.

Other symptoms are Im able to browse the internet just fine, and able to ping a host by its IP. Not by name, however. This applies to every network I am on. I am running a Windows 7 machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem.

Comment: it does. I am able to browse, however.

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is 'WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT 10106 Service provider failed to initialize. The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. This error is returned if either a service provider's DLL could not be loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup function failed.' Something wrong with your installation.

Comment: I have actually seen that. Also, it seems like the provider order gets messed up sometimes. Could anybody share theirs if they have a Windows 7 machine? I made a back up of my registry before messing with it, over writing my old back up (which hopefully could have fixed the issue. ...)

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: I was asking for the ProviderOrder value in the registry. Thanks for (potential) assist, btw :) I guess the issue was something with winsock2 and all that needed to happen is it needed to be reset (netsh winsock reset). Not really sure what the underlying issue is, since a sysadmin at work figured it out for me.